# Algebra to JavaScript

Tags: algebra, javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and need to turn my algebraic expression into a JavaScript function, just a function.  I'm self learning JavaScript.

Here's my expression... 
I can't post an image so this will have to do, sorry!

```
30* ( a*b - pi * ( ( C/2 ) ^2 ) ) + 20 * pi ( ( C/2 ) ^2 )
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function blah(a,b,C) {
    return 30* ( a*b - Math.PI * ( ( C/2 ) * ( C/2 )) ) + 20 * Math.PI ( ( C/2 ) * ( C/2 ) );
}
```

Comment: `(C/2)*(C/2)` hurts me. What if they wanted ^10 instead? You should just use `Math.Pow(C/2, 2)`

Comment: @o.v.: `Math.pow` is often (sometimes substantially) slower than multiplying manually. See benchmarks [1](http://jsperf.com/mathpow), [2](http://jsperf.com/math-pow-x-2-vs-x-x-by-craig).

Comment: the only vairbles that can change are the a, b, c not the powers, that' the point of the sum.

Comment: @icktoofay: that may be, but it's my understanding the question is about having an expression *translated* into JS

Comment: @o.v.: Yes, and `(C / 2) * (C / 2)` and `Math.pow(C / 2, 2)` are the same excepting some performance characteristics. It's translation either way.

Comment: @icktoofay: I get lost in semantics sometimes - but I don't think "translate" means "translate and optimize for performance" :)

Comment: @o.v.: Perhaps you're right, but I think that it's more likely that the OP would not want some code that is much slower than some other equivalent code, given that they're both easy to understand, although one is closer to the original expression.

Answer (score 2):

We could simplify the computation a bit like:

```
var exp = function (a, b, c) {
    var x1 = Math.PI * Math.pow(c/2, 2);
    return 30 * (a * b - x1) + 20 * x1;
};
```

You can call the function like:

```
exp(2, 1, 0);
```